# startActivityForResult() working after I click it again?

Tags: android

Guys I have **2 activity**  when I clicked button in main starting new activity(message.java) and I'm trying to get data from my **message** activity
to **mainActivity** .In message activity, I have edittext and when clicked button go back mainactivity and show that info in textview. This code working but problem is when I clicked button in **mainActivity**
it's first delete textview's text and then **message** activity begining . This is not what I want and also , it's taking info from **message activity** that's OK but in **mainActivity** I must clicked again mainActivtiy button to show in textview. Any suggest?

This is what I want
[image]

This picture shows problem 
[image]

Parent -> **MainActivity**

Child ->**message**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RelativeLayout rLayout;
private Button bt,bt2;
private TextView tv;
private String s;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    bt2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    final Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MessageActivity.class);
    bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            tv.setText(s);
        }
    });
}//end of onCreate

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                s=data.getStringExtra("info");

            }
        }
    }
}//end of mainActivity
```

here message.java

```
public class MessageActivity extends Activity {
private Button bt;
private TextView tv;
private EditText et;
private String s;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.message);

    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent data = new Intent();
            s=et.getText().toString();
            data.putExtra("info", s);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you would like to show your text in MainActivity when you come back from MessageActivity, you should just be setting the text in onActivityResult() method, not in the clickListener.
So your code will look like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            s=data.getStringExtra("info");
            tv.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I want add a lot of card in button click how can I done it?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Give an example.

Comment: Assume I'm making card with a class and there is a function that returning a cardview so every time I  will call that returning function many times...  and also I want to use this function in main 4 times with 4 button . At this point with this technique , in mainactivity, I need to write all function calls in onActivityResult() . This is not useful , isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to set the textView text in the activity result function. Is the better place to do it. Think than when you start a child Activity, the flow of parent activity stops. And when you finish child activity, flow goes directly to onActivityResult function. Try it. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity you need to set the text on your textview once you receive it. Problem is that startActivityForResult is asynchronous call. Once call to this method is gone it will start other activity but your onClick() method will not stop here. Its a normal listener that calls onActivityResult when your activity is destroyed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RelativeLayout rLayout;
private Button bt,bt2;
private TextView tv;
private String s;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    bt2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    final Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MessageActivity.class);
    bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });
}//end of onCreate

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                s=data.getStringExtra("info");
                tv.setText(s);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Accept and upvote if it works.